# Tkinter second App window updating after the execution reaches last line

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Tkinter and I'm facing issue of updating the listbox in second window.
The issue is the listbox in secondary window get updated only after the execution reaches to last line and not in the middle.

At First the secondary window was popping after the execution reached last line but used **app.lift()** function lift it but it's not updating

Here is the short snippet of code :

```
class Demo:
    def m1(LB1):
        for i in range(10):
            #rest of code
            LB1.insert(END,i) 


def f1():
    app2 = Tk()
    app2.title("PROCESSING")
    app2.geometry("350x50")
    app2.lift()
    LB1 = Listbox(app2, height=25, width=100)
    obj = Demo()
    obj.m1(LB1)


def main():
    app = Tk()
    app.title("APP")
    #rest of code
    b1 = Button(app, text="start", height=1, width=80, command=f1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Change `app2 = Tk()` to `app2 = Toplevel()`

Comment: @TheLizzard Thanks fr replying.....Tried it's not updating bro

Comment: @TheLizzard found app2.update() but is it efficient to update whole app for update listbox

Comment: it is not a good practice in general to use `.update()` since it can cause problems so You are better off with `.after()` tho from an efficiency standpoint it certainly won't cause problems (I am only as certain as my testing was, which also did not include a lot of stuff but around 500 windows opened pretty smoothly while loading one label in a for loop and `update()`ing but as I said You shouldn't use `.update()`

Comment: also that class seems a bit pointless, it should better be just a function

Comment: if You want to use classes I suggest creating a class for that second window

Comment: also I just noticed the biggest flaw (first of You should do: `app2 = Toplevel()` as suggested): You are not adding the listbox to the window, You should under the `LB1 = Listbox(app2, height=25, width=100)` add this line: `LB1.pack()` or use any other layout option like `.grid()` or `.place()` (`.place()` isn't the best option tho in many cases)

Comment: Thanks @Matiiss ,TheLizzard for helping, After searching found out that listbox can be updated itself. so what I did was instead of updating whole app just updated the listbox using **LB1.update()** it did the job

Comment: @Matiiss regarding using class actually I have other code there which executes and then it's updates the listbox

Comment: @Suraj I don't remember if I mentioned it already but using update() may not be the best practice (maybe for a single controlled label it is fine, but..idk). there is certainly a way to do it without .update() (if I have time will show You) otherwise at least You have a solution

Comment: @Matiiss Sure, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used **LB1.update()** for updating the listbox instead of whole app it actually updated the listbox in each iteration.

Solution:

```
def m1(LB1):
        for i in range(10):
            #rest of code
            LB1.insert(END,i)
            LB1.update()   #this will update the listbox
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I made some code hope it helps (I also am a bit confused by what You mean that it doesn't update, like it shows an empty listbox or what?) Also I didn't mention it in comments but that is not really how You create classes:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, Button, Listbox


def second():
    top = Toplevel(root)
    top.focus_force()

    listbox = Listbox(top)
    listbox.pack()

    for i in range(10):
        listbox.insert('end', i)


root = Tk()

Button(root, text='Open', command=second).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

By the way the code will still display the listbox after finishing inserting or sth but it just happens super quickly (I tried with 10000 entries (which are just number but sill happened almost instantly)).

Comment: Thanks for this code but my main issue was that the lostbox should e updated with every entry so the upper solved the problem again thanks for your time!!!